# Large Operation error when sorting in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a user that has the following issue. In Excel, when sorting all the cells they get this warning "The operation you are about to perform affects a large number of cells and may take a significant amount of time to complete. Are you sure you want to continue?"

They have been using this spreadsheet this way for years and only now has this issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this workbook growing in size, or is there a cleanup on data every now and then?

Comment: It keeps growing in size.

Comment: Then the message your user is getting is pretty obvious, your data has grown too large and needs more time computing changes. You can do 3 things: wait for the workbook to recalculate, rethink how you build up the workbook or consider an alternative for excel.